# Best way to implement depedent choices in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django model called CarAd which is implemented as follows:

```
class CarAd(models.Model):
    MAKE = (
            (0, 'Acura'), (1, 'Alpha Romeo'), (2, 'Aston'), (3, 'Toyota'), (4, 'Honda')
        )

    make = models.IntegerField(choices=MAKE)
```

I want to implement it such that each make has a subset of car models (*not Django models*). For example,  Toyota has a subset with elements 'Corolla', 'Prius', and 'Camry'. I want to provide the list of this subset based on what user selects as the make of the car.

For example, if he selects, Toyota, he should be provided with 'Corolla', 'Prius', and 'Camry'. If he selects Honda, he should be provided with 'Civic', 'City', 'Accord' and so on. How am I supposed to acheive this in the best possible manner without using any separate model(s)/Foreign keys? Note that these lists are static.

Answer (score 2):

```
class CarAd(models.Model):
    MAKE_HONDA = 0
    MAKE_TOYOTA = 1
    MAKES = ((MAKE_HONDA, 'Honda'),
             (MAKE_TOYOTA, 'Toyota'),)

    MODELS = { MAKE_HONDA: ('Civic', 'City',),
               MAKE_TOYOTA: ('Corolla', 'Prius',)
             }

    make = models.IntegerField(choices=MAKES)

# Django Form
class CarAdForm(forms.Form):
    make = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CarAd.MAKES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Car make
        make = args[0]['make']
        models = CarAd.MODELS[make]
        self.fields['models'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=models)
```